# No newline at end of file causing "Unexpected token ILLEGAL" error?

Tags: javascript, git, cakephp, vim, eol

I did a pull of some commits from colleagues and encountered some ^M characters which I got rid of in my file using :set ff=unix.

However when I load the page, it complains with "Unexpected token ILLEGAL" with regard to some JS that was working just perfectly before.

I look at the git diff and the only thing it can tell me is "No newline at end of file" - which despite reading up on has still left me stumped as why this would put my JS out of whack.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Open vim and save the file. vim will automatically add a newline to the end of the file.

Comment: @FDinoff already done that - not helped.

Comment: Did you cut/paste the code into your text editor? Carriage returns won't hurt anything, and neither will a missing line terminator. Your problem is probably a stray Unicode character.

Comment: You're probably missing a semicolon somewhere too. That and the lack of newlines can cause modules or functions to be passed into other functions as parameters, breaking *everything*.

Comment: @Pointy no changes have been made to this file between it working and not working - perhaps a hidden character?

Comment: I strongly suspect that the file *has* changed, unless your computer is haunted. Yes, a hidden Unicode character is a common cause of this, and such characters often come from sites like JSFiddle via cut/paste. Try re-typing (manually, not cut/paste) the code around the spot where the error is reported.

Comment: If I remove the file completely its still gives me the error - but goes away if I do a git checkout of the file!

Answer (score 0):

You could have solved the problem by either issuing a search/replace command in Vim:

```
:1,$s/^M//g
```

(on *nix system, type CTRL+V then CTRL+M to obtain the `^M` character)

Or you could also use `dos2unix` on your file from a shell:

```
[user@host]$ dos2unix path/to/your/file
```

Comment: Neither of these has helped. I still have the problem.

Comment: It could be that there is a BOM character in your file. What does the following command gives you? `file -i path/to/your/file`

Comment: it tells me it is a regular file ": regular file".

Comment: can you provide the whole output issued by the command? don't forget the `-i` option, so that the `file`  command give the MIME type string